# How to access HttpContext.Current.Application on OWIN Startup

Tags: asp.net-web-api, owin, httpcontext

I need to fill `HttpContext.Current.Application["Translations"]` on OWIN startup, but `HttpContext.Current` is `null` there.

Should I use `Application_Start()` in `Global.asax.cs` or it is bad idea?

What alternatives do I have?

Comment: HttpContext is not available at start up as it cannot exist without a request. `Begin_Request`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`HttpContext` is not available at start up as it cannot exist without a request. The Startup class only runs once for the application, not for each request.

Try accessing it in the `BeginRequest` handler in `Global.asax.cs`.

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e) {

    base.Application["Translations"] = "My value here";

}
```

Comment: Is it ok to use `Global.asax.cs` when I use OWIN? Guide I used said to delete it.

Comment: There should be no problem there provided it is not self hosted. if your are using Global.asax the assumption is that it is being host in IIS. The two can co-exist

Comment: Thanks, I will try as you suggested then.

Comment: A better approach that remains pure to Owin would be to write middleware to handle this.

Comment: @RonDeFreitas, that sounds interesting. I had not thought of that. How would one go about doing it via middle ware.